# Call back issue of this Error in $A.getCallback() [Unable to get property 'setParams' of undefined or null reference]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, case, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

This My requirement on case(Ticket) object

1. Get the all available Record Types(rec1,rec2,rec3) for that object.
2. Make them available as a list for selection on component.
3. Pass the selected recordTypeId as second parameter to force:createRecord.

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="HVHCRTIR_TicketCreationWithRecTypeCon" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchListOfRecordTypes}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="lstOfRecordType" type="String[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false" />

  <div class="slds-m-around--x-large">
    <lightning:button label="Create a Ticket" onclick="{!c.openModal}" />
  </div>    
   <!-- Model Box Start -->    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
        <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">
                        X<span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Case</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-2">
                             <div class="slds-align--absolute-center">Select a Record Type</div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-2">
                            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectid">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfRecordType}" var="case">                            
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!case}" label="{!case}"  />
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </ui:inputSelect>
                        </div>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </div>                   
                </div>

                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">Cancel</lightning:button>
                    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.createRecord}">Continue</lightning:button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class HVHCRTIR_TicketCreationWithRecTypeCon {
public static Map<Id, String> recordtypemap {get;set;}

   @AuraEnabled        
    public static List<String> fetchRecordTypeValues(){
        List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypes = Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();    
        recordtypemap = new Map<Id, String>();
        for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
            if(rt.getName() != 'Master')
            recordtypemap.put(rt.getRecordTypeId(), rt.getName());
        }        
        return recordtypemap.values();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id getRecTypeId(String recordTypeLabel){
        Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();        
        return recid;
    }      
}
```

Business Controller:

```
({


   fetchListOfRecordTypes: function(component, event, helper) {
      var action = component.get("c.fetchRecordTypeValues");
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
         component.set("v.lstOfRecordType", response.getReturnValue());
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },


   createRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);

      var action = component.get("c.getRecTypeId");
      var recordTypeLabel = component.find("selectid").get("v.value");
      action.setParams({
         "recordTypeLabel": recordTypeLabel
      });
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {debugger;
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {debugger;
            var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
             var RecTypeID  = response.getReturnValue();

            createRecordEvent.setParams({
               "entityApiName": "case",
               "recordTypeId": RecTypeID
                //var RecTypeID  = response.getReturnValue();
            });
            createRecordEvent.fire();

         } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
               "title": "Oops!",
               "message": "No Internet Connection"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();

         } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
               "title": "Error!",
               "message": "Please contact your administrator"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
         }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },

   closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
      // set "isOpen" attribute to false for hide/close model box 
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
   },

   openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
      // set "isOpen" attribute to true to show model box
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },
})
```

Error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [Unable to get property 'setParams' of undefined or
>   null reference] Callback failed:
>   apex://HVHCRTIR_TicketCreationWithRecTypeCon/ACTION$getRecTypeId
>   Failing descriptor: {markup://c:HVHCRTIR_TicketCreationWithRecTypeCom}

Comment: Is it here? `var action = component.get("c.getRecTypeId");` may see like a shot in the dark but you have a var named RecTypeId as well. trying renaming `var recTypeId` to `var = recordTypeId` so the variable name does not match the apex class name. Typically what you see is due to a clash but this was the only instance of the same name I could find in the code you posted. You only have two apex method actions that I saw so check for conflicts with those and other var names. Also make sure your compiled class has the methods, maybe you forgot to save??

Comment: are you running in standalone app,"e.force:showToast and e.force:createRecord" event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported only in Lightning Experience, Salesforce1, and Lightning communities.

Comment: try debuging - on the apex use `system.debug("this is the recid: " + recid);` before returning the message. Also on you client side controller alert the returned recid before using it: `alert(RecTypeID);`